# How do I set up a geographic mirror site for LAMP?

Tags: replication, mirror

I have a server that's running on the standard LAMP stack.  I have web services that read a MySQL database to control access to certain content.  If the content is allowed to be accessed then it is delivered to the user.

Recently I have been asked to create a mirror site in a different geographic region.  Assuming that I can get server replicating so that each instance is always in synch, how do I have my domain name decide which server to pick depending on which is the closest to the end user?  Any guidance or resources will help.  I am having trouble finding any current information.  Also I use Amazon Web Services if this can be handled aside from webserver configuration then I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Set up your name server to return the right IP based on the client location, but make sure it implements e-dns-client-subnet.

See also http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/43437/setting-up-your-own-geolocated-dns-services